# Volume of a cone in function of the slant angle

Tags: geometry, optimization, volume, spheres

In the figure, the cone has radius $r$, height $h$ and slant angle $\theta$, and the inscribed sphere has radius $R$ and center $O$.

[image]
The problem has 2 questions:

$a.$ $\space$ Compute the volume of the cone, in function of $\theta$

$b.$ $\space$ Which slant angle should be used to minimize the volume of the cone?

**My try**

For $a:$

It's easy to see that $HODC$ is a deltoid, so $$tan(\frac{θ}{2})=\frac{R}{r}$$
or $$r=\frac{R}{tan(\frac{θ}{2})}$$

and $$tan(θ)=\frac{h}{r}$$ or $$r\cdot tan(θ)=h$$ or $$\frac{R}{tan(\frac{θ}{2})}\cdot tan(θ)=h$$

Using this $r$ and $h$ in the formula for the volume of the cone:

$$V_{cone}=\frac{\pi R^3 tan(θ)}{3\cdot tan^3(\frac{θ}{2})}$$

but after this i don't see how to proceed to express $R$ in function of θ.

For $b$, i think i just need to find the final expression for $a$, and minimize that expression, because in $b$, $R$ is constant.

Any hints?

Comment: $R$ is a constant. So you should be well on your way!

Comment: The problem with question part a is it needs to be a function of more than one variable. For example, even when $\theta=30$, $r$ can change a lot, and the volume is a function dependent on r.